# How to print both the index and value for every element in a Vec?

Tags: vector, rust, iterator

I'm trying to complete the activity at the bottom of [this page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/hello/print/print_display/testcase_list.html), where I need to print the index of each element as well as the value. I'm starting from the code

```
use std::fmt; // Import the `fmt` module.

// Define a structure named `List` containing a `Vec`.
struct List(Vec<i32>);

impl fmt::Display for List {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        // Extract the value using tuple indexing
        // and create a reference to `vec`.
        let vec = &self.0;

        write!(f, "[")?;

        // Iterate over `vec` in `v` while enumerating the iteration
        // count in `count`.
        for (count, v) in vec.iter().enumerate() {
            // For every element except the first, add a comma.
            // Use the ? operator, or try!, to return on errors.
            if count != 0 { write!(f, ", ")?; }
            write!(f, "{}", v)?;
        }

        // Close the opened bracket and return a fmt::Result value
        write!(f, "]")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = List(vec![1, 2, 3]);
    println!("{}", v);
}
```

I'm brand new to coding and I'm learning Rust by working my way through the Rust docs and Rust by Example. I'm totally stuck on this.

Comment: Picking Rust as a first language may be a bit tough, as most of the learning resources assume one already knows how to "program". I'd advise you to hop onto the [Rust chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62927/rust) for more interactive help, especially when a concept doesn't seem to make sense to you!

Comment: Thanks @MatthieuM.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the book you can see this line:

```
for (count, v) in vec.iter().enumerate()
```

If you look at the documentation, you can see a lot of useful functions for `Iterator` and [`enumerate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate)'s description states:

> Creates an iterator which gives the current iteration count as well as the next value.
>
> The iterator returned yields pairs `(i, val)`, where i is the current index of iteration and val is the value returned by the iterator.
>
> `enumerate()` keeps its count as a `usize`. If you want to count by a different sized integer, the zip function provides similar functionality.

With this, you have the index of each element in your vector. The simple way to do what you want is to use `count`:

```
write!(f, "{}: {}", count, v)?;
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example to print the index and value of a vector:

```
fn main() {
    let vec1 = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    println!("length is {}", vec1.len());
    for x in 0..vec1.len() {
        println!("{} {}", x, vec1[x]);
    }
}
```

This program output is -

```
length is 5
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
```

Comment: This may be correct, but doesn't fit the code that OP is starting from. Directly using the indexing operator is also non-idiomatic when it's not required.