# How would you iterate over an array of 3 strings?

Tags: rust

How would you iterate over the following array in Rust?

```
const ARRAY: [&'static str;3] = ["red", "blue","green"];
```

I know in a language like say Lua, you would do:

```lua
for i, v in ipairs(ARRAY) do
    print(i, v)
end
```

And I mention that because I saw something similar syntactically in Rust in this post:

[How to print both the index and value for every element in a Vec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54795989/how-to-print-both-the-index-and-value-for-every-element-in-a-vec)

But I am still trying to wrap my mind around vectors and other Rust concepts as it relates to arrays.

Comment: `ARRAY.into_iter().enumerate()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @BallpointBen guidance via comment, I was able to get a working for loop:

```
fn main() {
    const ARRAY: [&'static str;3] = ["red", "blue","green"];

    for (count, v) in ARRAY.into_iter().enumerate() {
        println!("{} {}", count, v);
    }
}
```

I still do not understand why there is two sets of curly braces as opposed to three, but this is working.

Comment: Why would there be 3 pairs of braces for 2 values, `count` and `v`

Comment: @cafce25, ahh the `count` and `v`, I thought the curly braces represented the number of elements in an array, still learning the meaning of that syntax.